# CSS: Perspective Hover Effect on Section

Tags: css, hover

Trying to get a hover effect to work hovering over a section (with no link). I've seen it used elsewhere but can't seem to get it right on my version.

To view what I'm trying to do, go to http://wpstaging.centerstaging.com/studios/studio-1/#specifications and attempt to hover over the first section which says 'Power'.

CSS:

```
.specs {
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.specs:before {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.15, 1);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-264deg, #52227f -50%, #ff004e 100%);
}
.specs:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0);
}
```

HTML (edited):

```
<section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section specs">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of standard selectors like class and id what you can use here is the attribute selectors. The "Power" Section in your code have a data-id attribute

[image]

which can be given styles like below.

```
[data-id^="44962df"]:hover {
background-image: linear-gradient(254deg, #52227F 50%, #FF004E 100%);
}
```

Resulting to this on hover

[image]

Comment: I see where you're going, but that doesn't explain how to do the CSS transform effect I want on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Took some experimentation, but here's what worked.

```
.specs:after { 
  background-image: linear-gradient(-264deg, #52227f -50%, #ff004e 100%)!important;
  content: "";
  height: 100%; 
  left: 0; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  position: absolute; 
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.15, 1);
  z-index: -1;
}
.specs:hover:after{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0);
}
```